# Sybase SQLAnywhere with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, windows, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to install Sybase SqlAnywhere using nodejs (v4.2.6).
But I keep getting the following error when I run this command:

```
npm install sqlanywhere --save
```

I tried installing build.js, even then I keep getting this below error.
Please can anyone advise where I am doing wrong.

[image]

Thanks,
WH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running the 32-bit version of node on a 64-bit machine. The SQL Anywhere node.js driver comes with the 64-bit version of the Windows libraries, and node-gyp doesn't work well on Windows.

Can you upgrade to a 64-bit version of node?